# How to write Hibernate Criteria for this sql Query?

Tags: java, mysql, json, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have a Query Like This

**Query**

```
SELECT attendance_entry.roll_no,attendance_entry.absent_date,attendance_entry.absent_status,attendance_entry.leave_status,attendance_entry.od_status 
   FROM  attendance,attendance_entry 
   WHERE attendance.class_id='"+classId+"' && 
    attendance.section_id='"+sectionId+"'  && 
    attendance_entry.absent_date= STR_TO_DATE('"+date+"','%a %b %d %H:%i:%s IST %Y')
    GROUP BY attendance_entry.roll_no";
```

I need to write criteria to Parse Json

I tried with following Criteria

```
Criteria cr = getSession().createCriteria(AttendanceEntry.class)
            .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
            .add(Projections.property("rollno"),"rollno")
            .add(Projections.property("absent"),"absent")
            .add(Projections.property("leave"),"leave")
            .add(Projections.property("od"),"od")
            .add(Projections.groupProperty("rollno"),"rollno"))
            .add(Restrictions.eq("attendance.classYear.id", classId))
            .add(Restrictions.eq("attendance.section.id", sectionId))
            .add(Restrictions.eq("absentDate", date))
            .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(AttendanceEntry.class));

            return  cr.list();
```

and i having the Following Error

**Error**

```
 could not resolve property: attendance.classYear.id of: com.technofolks.model.AttendanceEntry; nested exception is org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: attendance.classYear.id of: com.technofolks.model.AttendanceEntry
```

I have mapped attendance and Entry as onetomany and manytoone. How to Write Criteria Query?

Comment: Could you try it without ".id" for classYear and section?

Comment: Ya i tried without both ids. Its Works. But I need to check Class and Section Ids.

Comment: Oh think you got me wrong. Replace `Restrictions.eq("attendance.classYear.id", classId)` by `Restrictions.eq("attendance.classYear", classId)`. Reason for that is that if I remember correctly hibernate know in that situation that you are checking the id.

Comment: is anyother way to check class id and section id by this criteria? or i will get attendanceid from attendance table and i check with AttendanceEntry table?

Comment: Ya i tried without id-same Problem " could not resolve property: attendance.classYear of: com.technofolks.model.AttendanceEntry;" . In my POJO class  AttendanceEntry contains Attendance and Attendance contains ClassYear and Section. Is any need to change Pojo?

Comment: Usually not. Sorry didn't saw that you're using multiple tables so you need to join attendance. [This](http://kruders.com/hibernate/hibernate-criteria-on-multiple-tables/) could help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Criteria Works for my MySQL Query

```
@Override
@Transactional
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<AttendanceEntry> getAttendanceByDateSearch(String classId,  String sectionId, Date date) {
    Criteria cr = getSession().createCriteria(AttendanceEntry.class,"attendanceEntry")
        .createAlias("attendanceEntry.attendance","attendance")
        .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
        .add(Projections.property("rollno"),"rollno")
        .add(Projections.property("absent"),"absent")
        .add(Projections.property("leave"),"leave")
        .add(Projections.property("od"),"od")
        .add(Projections.property("absentDate"),"absentDate")
        .add(Projections.groupProperty("rollno"),"rollno"))
        .add(Restrictions.eq("attendance.classYear.id", classId))
        .add(Restrictions.eq("attendance.section.id", sectionId))
        .add(Restrictions.eq("absentDate", date))
        .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(AttendanceEntry.class));
        return  cr.list(); 
}
```